# Lasso 9 Hangs on Inserting Pair with Map Value into Array?

Tags: lasso-lang

**EDIT:** I accidentally misrepresented the problem when trying to pare-down the example code. A key part of my code is that I am attempting to sort the array after adding elements to it. The hang appears on *sort*, not insert. The following abstracted code will consistently hang:

```
<?=

local('a' = array)

#a->insert('test1' = map('a'='1'))
#a->insert('test2' = map('b'='2')) // comment-out to make work

#a->sort

#a

?>
```

I have a result set for which I want to insert a pair of values into an array for each unique key, as follows:

```
resultset(2) => {
    records => {
        if(!$logTypeClasses->contains(field('logTypeClass'))) => {
            local(i) = pair(field('logTypeClass'), map('title' = field('logType'), 'class' = field('logTypeClass')))
            log_critical(#i)
            $logTypeClasses->insert(#i) // Lasso hangs on this line, will return if commented-out
        }
    }
}
```

Strangely, I cannot insert the `#i` local variable into thread variable without Lasso hanging. I never receive an error, and the page never returns. It just hangs indefinitely.

I do see the pairs logged correctly, which leads me to believe that the pair-generating syntax is correct.

I can make the code work as long as the value side of the pair is not a map with values. In other words, it works when the value side of the pair is a string, or even an empty map. As soon as I add key=value parameters to the map, it fails.

I must be missing something obvious. Any pointers? Thanks in advance for your time and consideration.

Comment: Perhaps the value of the first item in the pair `field('logTypeClass')` is `null`?

Or is it some other data type?

You could also try stepping through it in LassoLab debugger to see exactly when it hangs.

Comment: You say you see the pairs logged correctly - is this just when the insert is commented out? Or do you see multiple pairs logged even with the insert? If it's not hanging on the first insert, then maybe something else is at play.

Comment: I've submitted a bug report to rhinotrac:
http://www.lassosoft.com/rhinotrac?id=7680

Comment: I can verify the bug with the basic code you sent with sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can verify the bug with the basic code you sent with sorting. The question does arise how exactly one sorts pairs. I'm betting you want them sorted by the first element in the pair, but I could also see the claim that they should be sorted by last element in the pair (by values instead of by keys)

One thing that might work better is to keep it as a map of maps. If you need the sorted data for some reason, you could do map->keys->asArray->sort

Ex:

```
local(data) = map('test1' = map('a'=2,'b'=3))
#data->insert('test2' = map('c'=33, 'd'=42))

local(keys) = #data->keys->asArray
#keys->sort
#keys
```

Even better, if you're going to just iterate through a sorted set, you can just use a query expression:

```
local(data) = map('test1' = map('a'=2,'b'=3))
#data->insert('test2' = map('c'=33, 'd'=42))

with elm in #data->eachPair
let key   = #elm->first
let value = #elm->second
order by #key
do { ... }
```

Comment: For the asked situation I don't see sorting the array as needed. Make sure the query for the records use proper sorting and the array will be sorted for you.

Comment: Absolutely going to utilize a query expression. This particular code comes from an old 8 project, so at first I didn't want to refactor too much. But it's time to get on board the 9 train. Thanks to Jolle as well.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you problem is the pair with map construct per se.
This test code works as expected:

```
var(testcontainer = array)

inline(-database = 'mysql', -table = 'help_topic', -findall) => {
    resultset(1) => {
        records => {
            if(!$testcontainer->contains(field('name'))) => {
                local(i) = pair(field('name'), map('description' = field('description'), 'name' = field('name')))
                $testcontainer->insert(#i)
            }
        }
    }
}
$testcontainer
```

When Lasso hangs like that with no feedback and no immediate crash it is usually trapped in some kind of infinite loop. I'm speculating that it might have to do with Lasso using references whenever possible. Maybe some part of your code is using a reference that references itself. Or something.